# how do I build a docker image without existing from a docker file

Tags: docker, dockerfile

new to dockers.

running this `docker build .`

this is the `Dockerfile`

```
FROM gcr.io/google_appengine/python

# Create a virtualenv for dependencies. This isolates these packages from
# system-level packages.
RUN virtualenv /env

# Setting these environment variables are the same as running
# source /env/bin/activate.
ENV VIRTUAL_ENV /env
ENV PATH /env/bin:$PATH

# Copy the application's requirements.txt and run pip to install all
# dependencies into the virtualenv.
#ADD requirements.txt /app/requirements.txt
#RUN pip install -r /app/requirements.txt

# Add the application source code.
ADD . /app

# Run a WSGI server to serve the application. gunicorn must be declared as
# a dependency in requirements.txt.
CMD gunicorn -b :$PORT main:app

CMD bash1  "while true; do echo hello; sleep 1;done"

CMD ["sh", "while true; do echo hello; sleep 1;done"]
CMD "echo" "Hello docker!"
```

but after, when I run `docker ps` I don't see the image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use 'docker run ' to create and run a container. all docker build does is create an image.

Answer (score 2):

To build an image you have to use:

```
docker build -t username/imagename .
```

You have to use `-t` to tag your image and give it a name, from the docs:

> -t, --tag value               Name and optionally a tag in the
>   'name:tag' format (default [])

Then you can see the list of your images using:

```
docker images
```

You are using `docker ps` which is for listing **containers** not images.

More info about [about images and containers](https://docs.docker.com/engine/getstarted/step_two/).

Check the [documentation on docker build](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/build/).